# How to locate and display a file

Tags: command-line, locate, xdg-open

I want to locate and display an image. Is there any way to do so using pipe or ...? I wanna locate image **X**, i do `locate X` and the path is shown, but i can't send the output to xdg-open.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`xdg-open` doesn't read from stdin. Use

```
locate X | xargs -L1  xdg-open
```

Comment: At least with the default `mlocate`, you can specify null termination so as to handle the case of filenames with whitespace e.g. `locate -0 X | xargs -0 xdg-open`

Answer (score 7):

You need to use:

```sh
xdg-open "$(locate X)"
```

If your file contains spaces/special characters you need to use:

```sh
xdg-open "$(locate "X")"
```

**Note**: This command must be directly used in terminal. Use of this command in shell scripting need to be avoided as it may generate errors or inconsistent outputs.

Comment: @AmanMittal: PerlDuck is absolutely right. Just change to a different directory and enter your command.